# Add models to backbone collection outside Marionette ItemView definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, backbone.js, marionette

I have two backbone collections rendered in divs like so:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="one">
            <-- Collection c1 rendered by Marionette ItemView App.V1 here -->
        </diV>

        <div id="two">
            <-- Collection c2 rendered by Marionette ItemView App.V2 here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to add models to collection `c1` (and `c2`) but all I know is the div id - `#one` and `#two` because `App.V1` and `App.V2` were rendered like so:

```
var App = new Marionette.Application();

App.addRegions= {
one: "#one",
two: "#two"
}

function r()
{
var c1= new C110;
c1.fetch();
var c2= new C220;
c2.fetch();
App.one.show(new App.V1({collection: c1});
App.two.show(new App.V2({collection: c2});
}
```

Where `App` is a global Marionette object; `one` is the region defined by div `#one` and `two` is the region defined by div `#two`.

My question is - How can I get hold of Collection `c1` or `c2` outside the definition of `App.V1`, `App.V2` and `r()` and add some models to them (if I call `r()` again, I create new `c1's` and `c2's` so `c1.add(...)` and `c2.add(....)` becomes useless)?

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the View objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the global Marionette object `App` holds the reference to all Views (which are currently alive in the DOM) and their respective collection.

So, in the above case, `c1` can be accessed like so: `App.one.currentView.collection` 
 Similarly `c2` can be accessed like so: `App.two.currentView.collection` 
(Remember that `one` and `two` are names of Marionette regions defined by `App` and not the names of `html div ids`)